# Conditional number of jobs in Gitlab-CI (bonus: GitHub actions)

Tags: github-actions, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to have a number of followup jobs in GitLab-CI depend on earlier jobs. Something like

```yaml
stages:
- collect
- test

collect data:
  stage: collect
  script: ...

test:
  stage: test
  script: ...
  parallel:
    matrix: [ something that depends on the collect job ]
```

That is, the first job would provide a list of future jobs to run.

The reason for this - in case I am missing a much better approach - is that I would like to have a state-dependent set of follow-up tasks on a custom runner. That is, the custom runner would collect some information about the current state of a system and select follow-up tasks depending on that.

I am more familiar with Gitlab-CI, but if there is a solution using GitHub I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: GitLab-CI and GitHub actions are very different. Please [edit] your post to ask about one only in each question.

Comment: I think that I would rather leave it as is; the main question is about Gitlab, but I am not wedded to that tool for the moment. If the only solution is by using GitHub, then I would happily hear that.

Comment: You can ask two questions. But every question must have a clear focus, or it’s liable to be closed. See [ask]

Comment: There isn't really two questions though. My experience is with Gitlab-CI (hence the framing) but I don't want to restrict myself to that solution. My question(s) aren't really "How can I do this with Gitlab-CI" and "how can I do this with GitHub actions", but more "how can I do this at all?"